# Removing the comment section from the youtube video page

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, userscripts

im trying to make a Userscript that removes the comments from the Youtube video page but cant get it to work i tried a lot of methods but keep getting different errors that lead into other errors and stuff

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
setTimeout(function(){
  document.document.querySelector("#comments")[0].remove()
}, 2000);
  });
```

i also tried this version

```
(function () {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      setTimeout(() => {(function () {
        var CommentSection = document.querySelector("#comments");
        if (CommentSection) {
          CommentSection.parentNode.removeChild(CommentSection);
        }
      })})
    }, false);
    console.log("should be removed //")
  })()
```

but both give errors the hard thing is that the comments dont load immediately but load slowly and separately

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting a CSS rule that hides the section would be easier.

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = '.ytd-comments { display: none; }';
```

The `.ytd-comments` is the container for all the comments on a video, so setting it to `display: none` will hide it.